SafeNet eToken 5110 Remote Code Signing via SSH on Windows VM
I am setting up a remote code signing server using a SafeNet eToken 5110. My setup consists of a Windows 11 host and a Windows 11 virtual machine (VM), where the VM has direct access to the SafeNet eToken. I access the VM remotely via SSH from the host.
What I want to do is create a script that will:

scp the file I want to sign over to the VM.
ssh into the VM.
run the signtool command on the VM to sign the file using the eToken.
scp the signed file back to the host.

This process works successfully under the following conditions:

When signed in as a local admin on the VM.
When signed in as a remote admin.
When signed in as a local user.

However, when I attempt to sign the code as a remote user (non-admin), I encounter the following error: "SignTool Error: No private key is available."
My goal is to get the process to work when accessing the VM as a non-admin remote user, as I prefer not to expose admin privileges over remote connections.
Has anyone encountered this issue or know how to resolve it?

How do you start ssh server and on which user account does it run?
